# asm vs asm-generic in linux headers -- are they same

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, driver, header-files, kali-linux

In my linux header files folder on my Kali kernal 5.7.0 headers included in include directory /usr/src/linux-headers-5.7.0-kali1-common/include. Inside this folders I have header files contained in sub-folders like asm-generic,linux,uapi,acpi,crypto,etc.. But inside header files, i.e. inside linux/module.h there there is one header file reference included like

```
    #include <asm/module.h>  // top of linux/module.h
```

But Actually I don't have asm folder that got included with my header files when I installed them.
So one solution that came to mind is. Probably solution: Change the references from asm/* to asm-generic/* as in from asm/module.h to asm-generic/module.h inside linux/module.h and other files which I may use. I like to know is asm and asm-generic are same? meaning they contains same files and structure or is there any difference i can cause problem

If I correct the directory name in include reference than Does it make sense, or I will get into problems when I compile the module if I change headers sub directories names in include list of header files from asm to asm-generic? If I dont do this the header files will be missing

Comment: I do not know kali-linux. I think it includes the headers also in an other place (arch specific). Linux kernel link `asm` to the relevant architecture (so you may need it, but also with the kernel configuration you are using). `asm-generic` are templates which new architectures could use (if they do not want to implement all) -- in My Debian kernel have headers are in /usr/include/asm and /usr/include/linux

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi what if I create asm folder in include/ and copied to it everything from asm-generic. It may compile if names were really wrong (I doubt this). Or not compile if asm-generic is really something exists and is separate from asm and internal to kernal (since there is asm directory but I think its in some other folder like uapi or etc. in include/). I will try both. Wish I could get any specific info. is there any forum that talks about kali kernal internals or where I can get info on is  asm-generic same as asm. which version of kernal u are using. is it ubantu?

Comment: If you want to compile a module, you need the exact same headers has the kernel used (and with complete configuration of the kernel). generic has not all files, and you need architecture specific data. I would check a package which build external modules, and I would look that package on how to get correct headers and compiler flags.

Comment: If you think you need to edit the kernel header files to change asm/ to asm-generic/, you must be doing something wrong. `#include <asm/module.h>` should actually include the file /usr/src/linux-headers-5.7.0-kali1-common/arch/x86/include/asm/module.h on your system (assuming your system architecture is x86).

Comment: These header files are only needed for building external kernel modules using the kbuild system. They should never be needed for building code that runs in user-space.

Comment: You have to get precompiled kernel source. Some of distributions may have built-in kernel source. Eg: Ubuntu. If you found nothing, checkout kali's kernel source and use `make modules_prepare` for preparing a out of tree build.

Comment: Found [this post](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-linux-kernel-headers-on-kali-linux-2-0-kali-sana/) should help. If you need more info, `kernel source` and `module` might help.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)` might be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short answer

They are not the same.

kernel developer might include asm-generic headers in a asm header while asm headers are the headers required for kernel modules.

You may get more info from following post

- [in linux kernel, asm or asm-generic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109396/in-linux-kernel-asm-or-asm-generic/13115158#13115158)
- [Linux kernel headers' organization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798561/linux-kernel-headers-organization/9900439#9900439)
- [linux module compilng missed folder asm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11730181/linux-module-compilng-missed-folder-asm)

### Take this question in another way.

It seems you're trying to make a kernel module.

To build a kernel module you need kernel-headers or compiled kernel source code. However I don't know kali linux, so I just provide generic suggestions here.

### Where to get them

- Some of distributions, like Ubuntu, have prebuilt linux-headers.

  - Eg: Ubuntu has it in `/usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include`
- Download it by `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

  - It seems kali linux 2.0 might need more operations. Found [this post](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-linux-kernel-headers-on-kali-linux-2-0-kali-sana/) might help.
- Build it yourself

  1. Checkout linux kernel code of your desired distro.
  2. Set up kernel config with `make menuconfig` ( You might get stumbled here a while.. many packages might be required )
  3. Compile kernel with `make modules_prepare` to compile essential Module.symvers for drivers. It take significant less time than compiling a full kernel.

I presume you already found a kernel module build example. If not, you may consult offical kernel module [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/kbuild/modules.html). It helps a lot if you take a while to read first two chapters.

Or another [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11730181/linux-module-compilng-missed-folder-asm)

Comment: Thanks. I dont need to include asm in headers but asm-generic. Since my linux headers installed on kali 5.7 does not have asm directory in include. Thank you very much. but can u please confirm that I dont not need to have asm in headers in my kernel modules that I am making and  modules that I download like e1000e from other places, instead I can have asm-generic in header.

Comment: @Alex You SHOULD find a way to get kernel headers with asm directory. That's the way to compile a kernel module. Since I don't know much about kali, I hope [this post](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-linux-kernel-headers-on-kali-linux-2-0-kali-sana/) helps. My suggestion is to checkout your kali kernel source code, where there should be asm directory for kernel module. [Recompiling the Kali Linux Kernel](https://www.kali.org/docs/development/recompiling-the-kali-linux-kernel/) might help as well.

Comment: @Alex Note that kernel module should be portable in some way, so you should find headers with the same name across different distribution of kernels. That's why I presume kali should have `asm\module.h`.

Comment: Can u please take a look at this question. Its on this page question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65719389/linux-headers-makefile-checking-empty-variable-and-so-not-able-to-include-header

Comment: @Alex It's been removed. You may edit your current question if it's related.

Answer (score 1):

I found my asm directory at

```
/usr/src/{headers}/arch/{myArch}/include/asm
```

and

```
/usr/include/{myarch}/asm
```

Maybe you can find there too (I hope).