# Building GCC from source on Alpine: <asm/param.h> not found

Tags: docker, gcc, alpine-linux

When building `GCC` from source in a Docker container I get the error

> <asm/param.h> no such file or directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install the Linux headers via `apk add linux-headers`.

Related: [asm vs asm-generic in linux headers -- are they same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65591871/asm-vs-asm-generic-in-linux-headers-are-they-same)